Can an EU resident sue a US company for violating GDPR?
Can a US company that doesn't have a physical EU presence be sued for violating GDPR?

Possible duplicate of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/102038/under-which-federal-and-or-state-laws-could-gdpr-be-enforced-in-the-united-sta

This question is similar to: Under which federal and / or state laws could GDPR be enforced in the United States?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The linked question is subtly different in that it disallows the possibility of enforcing the GDPR from an EU member state (which may or may not have consequences to the US company).  Mind you, I still support closure.
